# set permalink for product filter

Tags: woocommerce

We have a lot of products in our shop. So I found a filter to a certain product type for which  I would set a nice link to. For instance in the category "blouse" (is a category) all which are "white" (is an attribute) and made out of "silk" (is an attribute).

The filter might look something like: www.myshop.com/shop/?filter_colour=230&filter_fabric=115

And I would like to set a permalink to this filter which is something like: www.myshop.com/ship/White_Silk_Blouses

Is that possible and how do I do it?

Comment: Yes it's possible to do with `.htaccess`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to achieve this by using the `Pretty Link` plugin:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/pretty-link/

---

**edit:**

If you don't want to use another plugin then you can use `add_rewrite_rule`:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule